# Difficulty Joining Three Tables in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join

i am having some difficulty joining the following statements.

```
Select *
From yr_property
Left Join yr_lease on yr_lease.propertynum = yr_property.propertynum
Where yr_lease.leasenum is null;



Select Dateto
From   yr_advert;
```

I have tried to join the tables, but i dont think everything is quite right

```
left join yr_advert on yr_advert.propertynum = yr_property.propertynum
```

I am aiming to...

List **properties** that aren't **leased** with the **date** that they were **last advertised** ( the date the last advertisement stopped).

**Tables in use**

**yr_property**

```
Propertynum , CHAR(5), NOT nullable (PRIMARY KEY 1) 
Street , VARCHAR(25),      nullable   
Area , VARCHAR2(15),       nullable 
City , VARCHAR2(15),       nullable 
Postcode , VARCHAR2(8),    nullable 
Prop_type , VARCHAR2(15),  nullable 
Rooms NUMBER , (2,0),      nullable 
Staffnum , CHAR(5),        nullable
Branchnum , CHAR(3)        nullable   
Ownernum , CHAR(5)         nullable
Comments , VARCHAR2(500)   nullable
Date_ended , DATE          nullable   **FORMAT EG - 11/JAN/2004**
```

**yr_lease**

```
Leasenum , CHAR(5),          NOT nullable (PRIMARY KEY 1) 
Renternum, ,  CHAR(5),       nullable   
Propertynum , CHAR(5),       nullable (FOREIGN KEY)
Paymentmethod , VARCHAR2(15),nullable 
Rent , NUMBER(17,2),         nullable 
Depositamount , NUMBER(15),  nullable 
Depositpaid , VARCHAR2(5),   nullable
Rentstart , DATE             nullable 
Rentfinish , DATE            nullable    **FORMAT EG - 11/JAN/2004**
```

**yr_advert**

```
ADVERTNUM ,    CHAR(10),    NOT nullable (PRIMARY KEY 1)
PROPERTYNUM ,  CHAR(5),     NOT nullable (PRIMARY KEY 2)
STAFFNUM ,  CHAR(5),          nullable
TOAPPEAR ,  VARCHAR2(100),    nullable
DATEFROM ,  DATE,             nullable  
DATETO ,  DATE ,              nullable   **FORMAT EG - 11/JAN/2004**
WORDS,  VARCHAR2(500),        nullable
```

Thank you for any help i may recieve.

Comment: You say `List properties that aren't leased with the date that they were last advertised.`  But this doesn't seem quite right since both the Lease and the AdVerts are date *ranges*.  Did you mean "*within*" the date range"?

Comment: The comments against the date columns are curious, as Oracle dates are not stored with a format. The format is decided by the NLS_DATE_FORMAT value, or an explicit format picture used in a To_Char() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is to find properties which haven't been leashed at the last its advertising period.

```
SELECT *
FROM yr_property A
INNER JOIN yr_advert B ON A.propertynum = B.propertynum
LEFT JOIN yr_lease C ON B.propertynum = C.propertynum AND (C.rentstart BETWEEN B.datefrom AND B.dateto OR C.rentfinish BETWEEN B.datefrom AND B.dateto)
WHERE B.dateto = (SELECT MAX(D.dateto) FROM yr_advert D WHERE A.propertynum = D.propertynum)
  AND C.leasenum IS NULL;
```

Alternative query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yr_property A
INNER JOIN yr_advert B ON A.propertynum = B.propertynum
WHERE B.dateto = (SELECT MAX(C.dateto) FROM yr_advert C WHERE A.propertynum = C.propertynum)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yr_lease D WHERE A.propertynum = D.propertynum AND (D.rentstart BETWEEN B.datefrom AND B.dateto OR D.rentfinish BETWEEN B.datefrom AND B.dateto));
```

I'm not quite sure which query is better in the matter of database performance.